# String to Date Format Conversion resulting in NULL - Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have date saved in the below format :

```
+-------------------------+
| timex    (varchar)      |
+-------------------------+
| 20200303                |
+-------------------------+
```

I want the output/convert the value into date /time format in Databricks SQL.

Should be :

```
+-------------------------+
| timex                   |
+-------------------------+
| 2020-03-03 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

Tried :

1. `select to_timestamp(timex)` --> results in 1970-xx-xx
2. `select to_timestamp(timex, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss')` --> says datatype in argument 1 should be in string or date
3. `select to_timestamp(CAST(timex AS STRING), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ssssss')` --> NULL
4. `select to_date(timex)` --> NULL

Equivalent in SQL - `convert(datetime,cast(timex as nvarchar),103)`

If I use cast(timex as string) as xx  --> it works
But, i I use to_timestamp(cast(timex as string), 'yyyyMMdd') as t --> it gives null.

I tried to format the string also to_timestamp(format_string('%8d',cast(timex as string)), 'yyyyMMdd') --> getting exception : IllegalFormatConversionException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert to timestamp using `to_timestamp` and then to the desired format using `date_format`:

```
select date_format(to_timestamp(format_string('%8d', timex), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
from mytable;
```

Comment: No, this is also giving NULL in Databricks.

Comment: timex is probably an integer. Try casting to string first. See edited answer.

Comment: I tried this - date_format(to_timestamp(CAST(timex AS STRING), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as xyz  .  Still giving NULL

Comment: could you show the result of `select cast(timex as string)`?

Comment: also could you show the result of `select date_format(to_timestamp('20200303', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')`?

Comment: select cast(timex as string) -- > this gives me 20200303. Ater that, its all null

Comment: select date_format(to_timestamp('20200303', 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')  --- > this gives 2020-03-03 00:00:00.000.

Comment: When I try to combine 2 thing, its giving NULL

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on your side. But you can try using `format_string` in the edited answer

Comment: Yea, its kind of weird  !  Now , I tried to the string format to UTF, I am getting this exception -  org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.  Does this says anything..

Comment: Could you show the complete message by editing your question?

Comment: The exception is -  IllegalFormatConversionException , if I try to format the string

Comment: No need to specify cast if you use format_string. please copy and paste my answer and try again

Comment: ok, this gives the exception, I just copy pasted your statement - IllegalFormatConversionException

Comment: what if you put 20200303 in place of timex? (note that 20200303 should be without quotes)

Comment: Yes, then I am getting the correct result.  I checked thhe datatpe , its a simple column with string datatype.  If I hardCode it (without quotes), it gives perfect result, not with the column name

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe something wrong with your database config.

Comment: seems so..let me check

Comment: Thanks @mck ,  it turned out, some data ends with 00, which is not appropriate for a DAY-value in timestamp function, resulting in a NULL.  But, I realize, it should give an error instead of NULL ( eg -  20231100 ) - > converting should give error, not null...Thanks a lot